# Python write() not writing the full string

Tags: python, hex, self-extracting

So I made a script where you put hex data in for something like an image or an audio file inside a variable and it then copies it into its own file (self extracts). However it doesn't work with a file over 2MB.

I've tested it with files up to 2MB and it works fine but when the hex data size is above 2MB it doesn't write the full output to the file and you end up with a file that's a fraction of the original size. Here is my code (the example hex data is just random):

```
import os
import binascii

def save_image(filename, hex_imgdata):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        current_file = open(filename, "wb")
    else:
        current_file = open(filename, "xb")
    decoded_imgdata = bytes.fromhex(hex_imgdata)
    current_file.write(decoded_imgdata)
    current_file.close()
    print("Saved " + filename)

example_hex = "A2C688B272"

if not os.path.exists("extracted"):
    os.mkdir("extracted")
os.chdir("extracted")

save_image(filename = "example.png", hex_imgdata = example_hex)
```

How can I make it work with larger files?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I changed your example to `example_hex = "A2" * 3_000_000` and got a 3,000,000 byte file.

Comment: I also added `print(os.stat("example.png").st_size)` to view the size. Can you make the same change and test so that we are working with identical code?

Comment: I tested with a 6 million character file and it only gave me less than half of it, try just copying the hex data of a random 6MB file and putting it in, also i will add that

Comment: The code you posted writes a 5 byte file. Can you post the code that fails? It should just be a larger `example_hex` string like what I suggested.

Comment: The written file will be half the size of the string because of the hex to binary conversion.

Comment: I can't send the exact example since I had to use a python write() script (which had the cutoff problem) to remove the spaces, but it was a .zip file with 10 audio files inside it, if you want I can upload the zip file somewhere and you can download it and copy the hex code, I also compared the original hex data with the copy I obtained from my code and it was identical until about halfway when the copy completely cut off so I don't think it's the conversion

Comment: It may be better to debug a bit first. It sounds like your failing code is different than what is posted here. I assume that `save_image` is the same in your code though? you could `print(len(hex_imgdata))` at the top of the function. Then, after the file is closed, add `assert os.stat(filename).st_size == len(hex_imgdata)/2, "Wrote all the data"`. Then you'd know what you wrote and whether data is lost in the function itself.

Comment: what does ``print(len(hex_imgdata))`` do? for me it just prints a number but what doe s the number mean?

Comment: You have a string hex_imgdata which is an ascii hex encoding of a binary file. It uses 2 characters to encode each byte. When you do fromhex, you should get a bytes object exactly half the size of the hex string. And you should end up with a file exactly the size of the bytes object. The extra debug I suggested helps to verify that. `print(len(hex_imgdata))` should give you a value twice the size of the resulting file.

Comment: it printed 2x the file's size but it's still less than the original file, how can i make it write all of it? is it too much data at once that i have to write certain amounts at a time? if so how would i go about doing that?

Comment: That is a very confusing statement. Was the hex string twice the size of the resulting file? What's this original file? This code doesn't show you reading an original file. Its just got a hex string and a write. It sounds like this part works. Is there other reading-file code envolved?